# Kendo Schedular Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTimezoneOffset' of undefined

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

```
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
        startTime: new Date("@DateTime.Now"),
        height: 600,
        views: [
            "day",
            { type: "workWeek", selected: true },
            "week",
            "month",
            "agenda",
            { type: "timeline", eventHeight: 50}
        ],
        timezone: "Etc/GMT",
        date: new Date("@DateTime.Now"),
        dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: url + "read",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                },
                update: {
                    url: url + "update",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: url + "create",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: url + "destory",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        return {
                            models: options.models, 
                        };
                    }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { from: "ID", type: "number" },
                        Title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                        Start: { type: "datetime", from:"Start" , format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"},
                        End: { type: "datetime", from: "End", format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" },
                        Description: { from: "Description" },
                        UserID: { from: "UserID", defaultValue: 1 },
                        IsAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                    }
                }
            },
            filter: {
                logic: "or",
                filters: [
                    { field: "UserID", operator: "eq", value: 1 },
                    { field: "UserID", operator: "eq", value: 2 }
                ]
            }
    },
    resources: [
            {
                field: "UserID",
                title: "Owner",
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                    { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                    { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
</script>
```

I've got this problem according the date property in the Kendo UI scheduler. It keeps saying that it's undefined but I'm really sure I defined it as you can see. I've been searching now for a while but I still haven't found the answer. Maybe someone could help me? I can provide every piece of could you would like to see.

Comment: Are you sure `new Date("@DateTime.Now")` is giving a valid date object? If the string content is not valid, it does not returns a date object.

Comment: well I've tried to enter multiple string and with different time formats! Even the  ones that are in the telerik examples but nothing seems to work...

Comment: Okay just found out that kendo wasn't doing anything wrong! its the default json serializer that fails! just use newtonsoft json serializer!!!